# CircleCIのCI(テスト自動化)の起動タイミングを指定出来るのか？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, rspec, circleci

お世話になります。
現在CircleCIを利用しCI設定を試みています。
現在RailsのRspecを使用していて、
ローカルからgithubに**git push origin 作業ブランチ** コマンドを実行した際にCIが起動したのは確認しました。
それともう一回、使用しているリモートの**作業ブランチ**から**origin/master**にマージした際にもCIが起動しました。
コード変更をしない事を前提に考えると、計２回CIが起動します。
これをリモートの作業ブランチからorigin/masterに**マージする時だけCIを起動**させ、
仮にそこでRspecテストが落ちたら、**マージを拒否する設定**は出来るのでしょうか？
どなたかご教授頂ければ幸いです、どうかよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

現在のところ CiecleCI で制御できるのは

- ブランチ名へのパターンマッチ(名前があるパターンのブランチの場合のみCIが走るとか)
- Pull Request が Open している場合のみCIが走る

の組み合わせしかないようです。

> マージする時だけCIを起動

のチームでの運用では通常 Pull Request でのレビューが発生すると思いますので、「Pull Request が Open している場合のみCIが走る」パターンを使えるかと思います。

そもそも、git ではマージは一旦ローカルリポジトリで行って、マージ結果をPushすることになるとおもいますので、「マージのタイミング」でCIを走らせることは不可能と思います。